# Facebook Ads Insights API Not returning data for one ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to pull some data from Facebook Ads Insights API and I get the correct data from one campaign/ad and with a different campaign/ad I get nothing.

It's "" vs. "{\"data\":[]}" (one is nothing at at, one is empty result)

The ad that returns data has a status of "Not Delivering" and the one that doesn't return anything has a status of "inactive". I only have two ads to work with currently. Can I not get data from inactive ads through the API? In the web interface the data is there. Is there a switch or something for inactive ads that I might not have or I might be sending incorrectly?

EDIT:

Actually, if I switch the order of which ad I pull first it changes which one returns nothing. Does Facebook Marketing API not like you pulling ad data one after the other? What is going on here?

Comment: Show us what your request looks like. Are you making two separate requests, are you requesting data for both in one via `ids` parameter, ...?

Comment: I'm making seperate requests. It seems to work if I build in some wait time... I guess Facebook doesn't like rapid consecutive requests.